# Connecting a Custom Class to the graphic interface

Tags: iphone

I need some help to get this right, please. I have created an iPad drawing app using a view controller (**MainViewController**) and a Custom Class which contains all the drawing code (**DrawView.m**). The **DrawView** class is implemented on an **UIView view** and the program works absolutely fine allowing to draw with finger touches. Erasing the drawing is accomplished by tapping a few times in sequence.

Now I would like to add more functionality (such as erasing the drawing and enabling undo and redo) by implementing some buttons. 
The problem is that despite having declared an outlet for the drawing in my **DrawView** class (**UIImageView** ***drawImage**) I cannot find a way of physically connect this outlet in interface builder to the graphic interface (**MainViewController_iPad.xib**).

Is there a way I can connect them please? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you actually declared the `IBOutlet` qualifier for `UIImageView *drawImage;`?

Comment: Yes I have, in the DrawView class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the results that I think you're looking for by the following steps:

- Create a new view controller subclass called `MainViewController_iPad` targeted for iPad and with a matching xib file.
- Create code for a `UIView` subclass called `DrawView`.
- Add a line to DrawView.h: `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *drawImage;` and synthesize the variable.
- Use IB to put a `UIView` and a `UIImageView` into my xib file.
- Change the class of the `UIView` to `DrawView` using the identity inspector.
- With the `DrawView` still selected change to the connections inspector.
- Drag a connection from the `drawImage` outlet to the `UIImageView` object.

Is there something in that different from what you're doing or am I missing a point in the question?

Comment: Not for the purpose of making the connection work. How its content actually gets defined would be a separate consideration.  (Though, I suppose if you loaded it from its own nib and it contained the `UIImageView`, you'd make the connection in that one instead of the view controller's xib.)

Comment: However I do have a problem... How can I refer to drawImage from MainViewController.m? It appears as undeclared there..

Comment: Same basic concept: create an IBOutlet in the main controller just like the one in DrawView and link it too.  (Or link to the DrawView and reference its property.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I was using @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *drawImage; rather than @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *drawImage; I made the changed and drawImage magically appeared! Thank you very much.